# Partial Fractions with multiple variables

Tags: partial-fractions

I have been trying this problem for a 1 week now but for some reason can not get my head around how to even approach this problem.
$$
\frac{\omega K}{(sT+1)(s^{2}+ \omega^{2})} 
$$
I first tried using the most straight forward way of using:
$$
\frac{\omega K}{(sT+1)(s^{2}+ \omega^{2})} = \frac{A}{(sT+1)} + \frac{B}{(s^{2}+ \omega^{2})}
$$
And then I expanded this and tried to equate coefficients but could not get anywhere.

Could someone help me just start this problem?

Thank You in advance

Comment: the variable is $s$, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it is

Comment: Sorry just realised the question had an error when I was typing it, it has now been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{s T+1}+\frac{b+c s}{s^2+\omega ^2}\quad(*)$$
add the fractions
$$\frac{s^2 (a+c T)+a \omega ^2+s (b T+c)+b}{(s T+1) \left(s^2+\omega ^2\right)}$$
numerator must be equal to the numerator of the given fraction
$$\frac{\omega K}{(sT+1)(s^{2}+ \omega^{2})}$$
so we have

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a \omega ^2+b=\omega  K \\
 c+b T=0 \\
 a+c T=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

which gives the solutions

$$a= T^2\,\color{red}{\frac{K  \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}},b= 1,\color{red}{\frac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}},c=-T\,\color{red}{\frac{K  \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}}$$

plug into $(*)$
$$\frac{T^2\color{red}{\left(\frac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}\right)}}{s T+1}+\frac{1\cdot\color{red}{\left(\frac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}\right)}- \color{red}{\left(\frac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}\right)} Ts}{s^2+\omega ^2}$$

Collect the common term $\dfrac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1}$

and the given fraction as

$$\frac{\omega K}{(sT+1)(s^{2}+ \omega^{2})}=\frac{K \omega }{T^2 \omega ^2+1} \left(\frac{T^2}{s T+1}+\frac{1-s T}{s^2+\omega ^2}\right)$$

Hope it is clear

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I understand the result up until you get the solution for a, b and c. Did you make each component the subject and then put it into the equation to get the results?

Comment: I collected the term in parenthesis which is common. I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: I am still not sure where you got the common term T^{2}\omega^{2} + 1

Comment: @MMS1986 I have rewritten part of the answer. Hope now is clear